# I want to convert a xml files into text file using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing

I have a xml file as

```
<annotation>
    <folder>all_images</folder>
    <filename>0.jpg</filename>
    <path>/home/vishnu/Documents/all_images/0.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>4250</width>
        <height>5500</height>
        <depth>1</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>word</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>308</xmin>
            <ymin>45</ymin>
            <xmax>502</xmax>
            <ymax>162</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
```

I want to convert this xml file into text file using python where the text file contains the dimensions (value) of xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax..For example
 I want to get the text file as

308,45,502,45,502,162,308,162,word

```
663,52,823,52,823,173,663,173,word

521,44,621,44,621,158,521,158,word
```

this.
..I have a number of such xml files ,want to convert it all into text files..Also want to loop it for number of such files.

Comment: OK. good luck with that. Edit your post when you try something yourself and/or have a question.

Comment: The output you're providing does not match with the description of the desired output. Please be more descriptive.

Comment: Here we consider the text file is contained in a box .Now considering the coordinates of the box as (xmin,ymin),(xmax,ymin),(xmax,ymax),(xmin,ymax) .we have these information in that xml file.I want to get the coordinates as text by iterating using python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a file called `file.xml`, containing:

```
<annotation>
    <folder>all_images</folder>
    <filename>0.jpg</filename>
    <path>/home/vishnu/Documents/all_images/0.jpg</path>
    <source>
        <database>Unknown</database>
    </source>
    <size>
        <width>4250</width>
        <height>5500</height>
        <depth>1</depth>
    </size>
    <segmented>0</segmented>
    <object>
        <name>word</name>
        <pose>Unspecified</pose>
        <truncated>0</truncated>
        <difficult>0</difficult>
        <bndbox>
            <xmin>308</xmin>
            <ymin>45</ymin>
            <xmax>502</xmax>
            <ymax>162</ymax>
        </bndbox>
    </object>
</annotation>
```

Then the following Python script in the same folder gives you an idea how to use the Standard Library [ElementTree API](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) to parse the file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse("file.xml")
root = tree.getroot()

print(root.find("./folder").text)
print(root.find("./object/name").text)
print(root.find("./object/bndbox/xmin").text)
```

You will need to work out how to write the values to your own text files, but that should be straightforward. There are lots of resources such as [this one](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/files/reading-and-writing-files-in-python).